# How to get full response in MS LUIS? (Python)

Tags: python, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to program a chatbot with machine learning entities and subentities. With LUIS Recognizer I can access the entities but not the subentities. The subentities or also called children are available in the raw response but not in the Recognizer. -> how can I read out these subentities?

Somebody had already a similar problem but was not really solved I think.
https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1348
The difference to his problem is that I want to code python instead of C# and want to use it for a self created ML Entity instead of the build-in datetimeV2.

Comment: Solved it my own :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Lib\site-packages\botbuilder\ai\luis
-> by opening the folder where the botbuilder lib is stored, luis_recognizer.py can be opened

For me it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmseO.png)

There it can be seen which init parameter the LuisRecognizer wants.
Now this parameters can be changed in when creating a new object in our own script.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmdjB.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).